# How to extract the AuthorityKeyIdentifier from a X509Certificate2 in .NET

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

I am looking for a way to extract the AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension from an X509Certificate2 instance.  I did not see any built-in support for this but since windows can properly construct a certificate chain I know the functionality has to exist at some level.  If the answer is to roll a DER parser, is there a good implementation that can be referenced?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Iterate through the extensions in the X509Certificate2.Extensions property and look for an extension with the OID 2.5.29.35 (as per http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.35.html). That is the AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension.

[Edit: Added the following.]

Each member of the Extensions property is an ASN encoded. So you can do the following to get it in a human readable or machine parsable format:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

...

X509Extension extension; // The OID 2.5.29.35 extension
AsnEncodedData asndata = new AsnEncodedData(extension.Oid, extension.RawData);
Console.WriteLine(asndata.Format(true));
```

For one of the Microsoft intermediate CA certificates, it the Format() method returns the following:

```
[1]Authority Info Access
     Access Method=Certification Authority Issuer (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
     Alternative Name:
          URL=http://www.microsoft.com/pki/certs/MicrosoftRootCert.crt
```

It is certainly not easy to parse but you can look for a line starting with the regular expression `\[\d+\]Authority Info Access` then find a line beneath it with the regular expression `URL=(.+)` (the eight spaces are unclear in the formatting) and use the URL in the parenthesized group.

Comment: Interestingly enough [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379070(v=vs.85).aspx) is telling me the OID is 2.5.29.1, but [rfc5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) agrees that the final segment is 35.  In any event the result is an Octet string and I want to extract out the encoded values.

Comment: Expanded the answer to show how to extract the extension to something human readable and, with a bit of effort, machine parsable.

Comment: Is that string always in English, even in other locales? I'm very surprised Microsoft doesn't give us a typed version of the output other than the string.

Comment: @ChrisBenard Good question. I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may interest, .NET 7 now supports it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509authoritykeyidentifierextension

Answer (score 0):

For me in 2024 the method with AsnEncodedData did not work. It returned an unreadable set of bytes.
And I need to work on net core 6 where is no x509authoritykeyidentifierextension.

So.. I had to make my own decision on this with BouncyCastle.

```
        using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
        using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;

        ...

        byte[] oid_2_5_29_35_raw = ...;

        var mainSequence = DerSequence.GetInstance(oid_2_5_29_35_raw);
        var content = DerOctetString.GetInstance(mainSequence[1]);
        
        var contentSequenceBytes = content.GetOctets().ToArray();
        var contentSequence = DerSequence.GetInstance(contentSequenceBytes);

        // 0 - Index in standart for keyIdentifier 
        var keyIdentifier = Hex.ToHexString(DerOctetString.GetInstance(contentSequence[0]).GetOctets());
        // 2 - Index in standart for authorityCertSerialNumber 
        var authorityCertSerialNumber = Hex.ToHexString(DerOctetString.GetInstance(contentSequence[2]).GetOctets());
```

I was looking for a solution for a long time=) maybe someone will find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

There's an easier option available - take some existing component that provides more flexibility in handling certificates. You can use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) or our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php).

Comment: Agreed; however, due to constraints I cannot include any open source software.  Thus the need for either built-in support or an in-house developed solution.

Comment: @Tedford What about commercial (ours)? :) Seriously, DER parser would also be third-party, and it's (due to low-level nature) harder to embed and deal with than high-level certificate management classes.

Comment: Sadly no, we cannot make additional capital expenditures at that point of the release cycle....perhaps in a future version.